# Are external resources part of assembly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, resources, .net-assembly

MSDN says:

> An assembly is a collection of types
>   and resources that forms a logical
>   unit of functionality.

What if I link a file to my application so it is not embedded (it is copied into output dir), it still part of assembly? Or it means only embedded resources?

Comment: No, the file does not become part of your assembly. It is just placed in the same directory on disk as your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

> In the .NET framework, **an assembly is
> a compiled code library** used for
> deployment, versioning, and security.
>
> There are two types: process
> assemblies (EXE) and library
> assemblies (DLL).
> A process assembly
> represents a process which will use
> classes defined in library assemblies.
>
> .NET assemblies contain code in CIL,
> which is usually generated from a CLI
> language, and then *compiled into
> machine language at runtime by the CLR
> just-in-time compiler.*
> - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly)

If your resource is just copied in the same folder it is not a part of your assembly.
But if it is compiled into a .dll or .exe it is a part of the assembly.

> For most .NET Framework applications,
> you locate assemblies that make up an
> application in the application's
> directory, in a subdirectory of the
> application's directory, or in the
> global assembly cache (if the assembly
> is shared).   -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3sywsc%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

---

*Also See*
[Assemblies in .NET: What they are and how to manage them](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/asmnet01.htm)